# PHP Binance composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I admit I am an amateur, and probably beyond help. I've taught myself some basic php a couple years ago and was able to write a simple bot for poloniex.

Now I want to right another one for binance. I just use XAMPP and set the php.ini max_execution_time to 0 so that it will run forever. The problem I'm having is getting it setup. For poloniex I just had a wrapper (or class?) file and an index file and I was set, but for binance I need to install composer and install dependencies... i dont even know. When I install the class it creates directory in the php folder called "vendor" there are examples in there and everything, but I can't run them unless they are in the htdocs directory. Any help and you would be so awesome. Sorry for being an idiot.

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-beginners-guide-to-composer

Comment: What does your php file look like, have you included the autoloader that is being generated by composer?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question... yes when I include autoloader it doesnt even load...

Comment: Have a look at the beginners guide. If this does not help you, share the code you use **in the question field** with a clear description of the missing pieces

Comment: I will look at that tutorial. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I finally just reinstalled xampp and composer and everything worked fine.